# Split multiple joined words with upper and lower case

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, pdf, text-mining

I found a few questions related with this subject. However, I haven't found a solution that brings a specific idea about how to split joined words (in Spanish)  with upper and lower case, using regex for example.

I'm using PyPDF2 in order to extract text from several pdfs. The information is always at the same order.

After run a PyPDF2 code I get items like these:

```
'MASCULINOFecha de NacimientoLugar de Nacimiento'
'CASADONivel Educativo'
```

In both cases, items are key words from pdf content. The output I'm trying to get should be like this (using the examples before):

```
'MASCULINO'
'Fecha de Nacimiento'
'Lugar de Nacimiento'
'CASADO'
'Nivel Educativo'
```

I tried regex module to split specific patterns. This is my code so far:

```
pdfFile = open('example.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFile)
for page in range(0, pdfReader.getNumPages()):
    text = pdfReader.getPage(page).extractText()
    for line in text.split(':'):
        pattern = re.compile(r'([A-Z][a-z]+(?=\s[A-Z])(?:\s[A-Z][a-z]+)+)')
        result = re.findall(pattern, line)
        print result
```

It splits a few items, but no all of them.

Is there a better regex pattern to split those kind of words?

Any suggestions to solve the problem are appreacite. Thanks

Comment: What's the original format of input ?

Comment: @noob I edited the question. At the end I wrote the code I'm working with.

Comment: Edit: How about a split on `\B(?=[A-Z][a-z])`. It splits before an uppercase letter followed by a lower case that isn't preceded by a space.

Comment: @ClasG: Close enough. But you will have to add `a-z` to positive lookbehind too.

Comment: Already changed - try again

Comment: @ClasG: Good one. Seems to be taking less steps than mine.

Comment: @ClasG Thanks. Should I add this pattern in variable `pattern`?

Comment: I'm not a python aficionado, and I don't know what form you want the result in, but I guess what you need to do is to change the pattern into the one suggested and change the `findall` to a `split`.

Comment: Thanks. I will try, @ClasG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])` and replace with `\n` or split.

This will detect the `zero-width` between upper or lower case AND upper or lower case. That seems to be logical separator here.

**Input**

```
MASCULINO|Fecha de Nacimiento|Lugar de Nacimiento
CASADO|Nivel Educativo
```

`|` denotes matched zero width.

**Output**

```
MASCULINO
Fecha de Nacimiento
Lugar de Nacimiento
CASADO
Nivel Educativo
```

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zC7eC8/1)**

As Wiktor mentioned in comment

> You cannot use re.split with an empty string matching regex. Use the PyPi regex module if you need split.
>
> There is no bug of this kind in re.sub, it is used as a workaround: you insert unused characters into the string with re.sub, and then re.split with this character. Just choose some char that is sure to be absent from the input (usually a control character, or a character from the unused Unicode range).

Substituting `~` in matched zero width and splitting on `~` will give you array of results.

**Python Code:**

```
import re
line='MASCULINOFecha de NacimientoLugar de Nacimiento CASADONivel Educativo'
result = re.sub('(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])', '~', line,)
result = re.split('~', result)
print result
```

**[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/nJQjIH)**

Comment: The Regex101 Demo looks great. I changed `re.findall` to `result = re.split(pattern, line)` But I have words joined as before.

Comment: @estebanpdl: Added ideone demo in my answer. Should be understandable now.

Comment: You cannot use `re.split` with an empty string matching regex. Use the PyPi *regex* module if you need *split*.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I wasn't aware of that so I used `sub` in demo. I hope that's alright or is there a better solution ?

Comment: @noob: There is no bug of this kind in `re.sub`, it is used as a workaround: you insert unused characters into the string with `re.sub`, and then `re.split` with this character. Just choose some char that is sure to be absent from the input (usually a control character, or a character from the unused Unicode range).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Thanks for the advice. Inserting unused characters really escaped my mind. Just used yesterday though.

Comment: @noob, thanks. It works great with upper cases. I didn't figure out that there are items like: `Edad:32` `question?:No` or  `Fecha de Nacimiento1977-02-16` or `Primer nombreALEJANDRA`; they are joined by numbers or are preceded by lower cases or specific characters like `:` `?` Is there a way to add some elements to the pattern?

Comment: @estebanpdl: In that case you can add numbers to lookahead or lookbehind as per need. If you could explain more it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Split on `\B(?=[A-Z][a-z])`. It'll find upper case letters followed by a lower case that is **not** preceded by a word boundary.

Done in the test case with 222 steps - [see it here](https://regex101.com/r/xX8vE3/1).

Regards

Comment: ▲ for clever use of `\B`.